# Bubble sort in java , method (static or non staic)? ,(void or int[] )?,instance variable needed?

Tags: java, sorting, methods, static-methods, bubble-sort

Can someone explain for me when do I use static /non-static 
, void or int[]x , and when do I use instance variables

because I can't seem to figure out which is when resulting in errors like this in the bubble sort code

```
public class PA2 {
//int []a ;
//int maxsize ;
//int temp;
public static int[] bubblesort(int [] a1) {
    int temp ;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<a.length-1-i;j++) {
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
       temp = a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=temp;
        }   
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a1 = {11,5,14,10,2};
     bubblesort(a1);
    //a.bubblesort();
   //a.selectionsort();
   // a.insertionsort();     }      }
```

Comment: All those options are valid. The answer is: it depends on your design or on how you intend to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to java and stackoverflow so if I used the int[] method  type what is the way I call the bubble sort method in the main method ? because it always does an error @ernest_k

Comment: looking at your `bubblesort` method, you wrote `public static int[]`, meaning that this method expects a `return` statement containing an `int array`. Perhaps this is the reason for the error you are getting, there are no return statements in your method. Currently, since you give an `int[]` as input, it would make sense to output/return the sorted array (i.e. `return a`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static /non-static:

**static** = something which is at the class level and shared by all the instances of that class. For example - `site_hit_count` would be an attribute you would like to maintain at the class level. No matter how many instances are created, all should see the latest and current value.
Application level caches (eg catalog information for all the products available) are also good example for static.

**non-static** = any class level attribute which will vary for each instance. For example - In a class called `Person` - name/age/address etc are instance level attributes but **NOT static** since each Person would have its own values to above attributes.

I would suggest you go through this language basic tutorial (this will clear a lot of above questions) - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: The types of method (void ,static void,int, static int … etc) how do I determine the type of the method I want to implement ?

Comment: regarding the rest of the question an error appears , but I cant determine whats the problem in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is something which can be used by multiple classes and codes, so it is better to have this as a Utility Method which are mostly written as static and using generics.